# Unable to make changes to table's sortable column background color

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding a table that I created long time back.

I had a table, for which the sortable columns had a blue background. I want to add another class to this table, say "sortable-table-white-bg" which when added to the table removes the blue background/adds white background to the sortable columns.

My table code is given below :

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="data-table sortable-table "
summary="JavaScript enabled sortable data table example">
    <caption><em>Sortable data table</em></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
            <th scope="col" class="abc-sort">
                <a href="#sort">
                    <span>Header 2</span>
                    <span class="abc-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="abc-numeric abc-sort">
                <a href="#sort">
                    <span>Header 3</span>
                    <span class="abc-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="abc-date abc-sort">
                <a href="#sort">
                    <span>Header 4</span>
                    <span class="abc-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="abc-table-row">This is a sample text</th>
            <td>Duis autem</td>
            <td class="abc-numeric">$1,234.56</td>
            <td>12 Dec 1999</td>
            <td>Ipsum dolor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="abc-table-row">This is a sample text</th>
            <td>Quis nostrud</td>
            <td class="abc-numeric">$789.10</td>
            <td>25 Jul 2007</td>
            <td>Adipscing</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="abc-table-row">This is a sample text</th>
            <td>Magna diam</td>
            <td class="abc-numeric">$1,112.13</td>
            <td>01 Jan 2000</td>
            <td>Sed diam</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the CSS for the table was :

```
table.data-table.sortable-table td.accent{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

table.data-table td.abc-sort-column{
    background:url(/i/v17/table_sort_col_background.gif) repeat-x 0px 0px ;

}

table.data-table tbody tr:first-child td.abc-sort-column{
    background: url(/i/v17/table_sort_col_background_child.gif) repeat 0 0 !important;
}
```

When we add the class "sortable-table-white-bg" to the table, I changed the CSS to

```
  table.data-table.sortable-table td.accent{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

table.sortable-table-white-bg td.abc-sort-column{
    background-color: #ffffff;

}

table.data-table td.abc-sort-column{
    background:url(/i/v17/table_sort_col_background.gif) repeat-x 0px 0px ;

}

table.sortable-table-white-bg tbody tr:first-child td.abc-sort-column{
    background-color: #ffffff ;

}

table.data-table tbody tr:first-child td.abc-sort-column{
    background: url(/i/v17/table_sort_col_background_child.gif) repeat 0 0 !important;
}
```

nothing changed ... I still see the same blue background.

Please help me out with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, the class "abc-sort-column" get added in the <td> automatically via javascript depending on the which column has been made sortable, the class "abc-sort" tells the which columns are sortable.

Answer (score 0):

Is because you use bot classes as table.data-table and table.sortable-table-white-bg.
Your code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="data-table sortable-table "
summary="JavaScript enabled sortable data table example">
```

You should define in css file just the classes without table.
Example:

```
.sortable-table-white-bg {  }
.data-table {  }
```

Or you have a script or a class that is re-writing your specific css class

Comment: And as i saw in you table class you typed just sortable-table and not sortable-table-white-bg

Comment: The class "sortable-table-white-bg" was added also when I was trying to test the code.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by several things.

1. The CSS refers to class named `abc-sort-column`, but there aren't any element in the HTML that has that class. Instead, the HTML only has elements named as `abc-sort`. Possible fix is to either change `abc-sort-column` to `abc-sort` in the CSS *or* `abc-sort` to `abc-sort-column` in the HTML.
2. The CSS that refers class names `abc-sort-column` explicitly select a `TD` element and in the HTML, there's no `TD` element with such class name. Presumable fix is to change the selector to use `TH` instead of `TD`.
3. If assuming `abc-sort-column` is supposed to be `abc-sort`, some CSS selectors explicitly specify `TBODY` element where in the HTML, there's no element with such class name. Presumably, the selector should be `THEAD` instead of `TBODY`.